# Easy way to convert a unicode list to a list containing python strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

Template of the list is:

```
EmployeeList =  [u'<EmpId>', u'<Name>', u'<Doj>', u'<Salary>']
```

I would like to convert from this

```
EmployeeList =  [u'1001', u'Karick', u'14-12-2020', u'1$']
```

to this:

```
EmployeeList =  ['1001', 'Karick', '14-12-2020', '1$']
```

After conversion, I am actually checking if "1001" exists in EmployeeList.values().

Comment: The correct answer to this question depends on what you want to happen if your input contains non-ASCII characters. If you are hoping that your input is all ASCII, then having the conversion throw an exception keeps you from silently converting `u'Kárick'` into `K\xc3\xa1rick` (which is sure to cause problems downstream if you aren't expecting it).

Comment: The input is dynamic and can sometimes contain non-ASCII characters, Trying to find the best possible solution to handle both ASCII and NON-ASCII inputs.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Just check for `u"1001"`.

Comment: To amplify @MarkTolonen, your data is already in the best form to handle Unicode information. By analogy to C, you might want to take a list of `int` and convert them to `short` and you might be fine most of the time. When you hit a datum that is larger than a short, you've just bought yourself a bug.

Comment: Yeah probably you are right with the output requirement. But I wasn't sure if evaluating u{SearchString} in [u <LIST>] is an optimal approach. So thought of converting the unicode list to a list containing strings to compare with the {{SearchString}}

Answer (score 54):

Encode each value in the list to a string:

```
[x.encode('UTF8') for x in EmployeeList]
```

You need to pick a valid encoding; don't use `str()` as that'll use the system default (for Python 2 that's ASCII) which will not encode all possible codepoints in a Unicode value.

UTF-8 is capable of encoding all of the Unicode standard, but any codepoint outside the ASCII range will lead to multiple bytes per character.

However, if all you want to do is test for a specific string, test for a *unicode* string and Python won't have to auto-encode all values when testing for that:

```
u'1001' in EmployeeList.values()
```

Comment: Given the OP's requirements clarification in the comments, this is possibly no longer the best answer. +/-0 because it was a fine answer when you wrote it.

Answer (score 20):

`[str(x) for x in EmployeeList]` would do a conversion, but it would fail if the unicode string characters do not lie in the ascii range.

```
>>> EmployeeList = [u'1001', u'Karick', u'14-12-2020', u'1$']
>>> [str(x) for x in EmployeeList]
['1001', 'Karick', '14-12-2020', '1$']


>>> EmployeeList = [u'1001', u'करिक', u'14-12-2020', u'1$']
>>> [str(x) for x in EmployeeList]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 14):

We can use `map` function

```
print map(str, EmployeeList)
```

Comment: Won't work for EmployeeList = [u'1001', u'करिक', u'14-12-2020', u'1$'] in Python 2.7

Comment: Worked well...Thnaks

Answer (score 7):

Just simply use this code

```
EmployeeList = eval(EmployeeList)
EmployeeList = [str(x) for x in EmployeeList]
```

Answer (score 5):

how about:

```
def fix_unicode(data):
    if isinstance(data, unicode):
        return data.encode('utf-8')
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        data = dict((fix_unicode(k), fix_unicode(data[k])) for k in data)
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for i in xrange(0, len(data)):
            data[i] = fix_unicode(data[i])
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
unicode_to_list = list(EmployeeList)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. I converted like this

```
def clean(s):
    s = s.replace("u'","")
    return re.sub("[\[\]\'\s]", '', s)

EmployeeList = [clean(i) for i in str(EmployeeList).split(',')]
```

After that you can check

```
if '1001' in EmployeeList:
    #do something
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using json and ast modules as follows

```
>>> import json, ast
>>>
>>> EmployeeList =  [u'1001', u'Karick', u'14-12-2020', u'1$']
>>>
>>> result_list = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(EmployeeList))
>>> result_list
['1001', 'Karick', '14-12-2020', '1$']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just json.dumps will fix the problem

json.dumps function actually converts all the unicode literals to string literals and it will be easy for us to load the data either in json file or csv file.

sample code:

```py
import json
EmployeeList =  [u'1001', u'Karick', u'14-12-2020', u'1$']
result_list = json.dumps(EmployeeList)
print result_list
```

output: ["1001", "Karick", "14-12-2020", "1$"]