# Python print unicode list

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-unicode

With the following code

```
lst = [u'\u5de5', u'\u5de5']
msg = repr(lst).decode('unicode-escape')
print msg
```

I got

```
[u'工', u'工']
```

How can I remove the leading `u` so that the content of `msg` is:

```
['工', '工']
```

Comment: What you are doing there gives me an `AttributeError`.

Comment: gongzhitaao, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @LucianU Trying to remove the leading convert the unicode code point to characters but removing the leading `u`.

Comment: @gongzhitaao, I was asking for the higher purpose of your code. If you just want to print the characters, it's enough to do `for c in lst: print c.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @LucianU Of course not :P.  I have no problem printing out them while removing the leading `u`.  I just need the unicode characters in a tring without `u`. :)

Comment: This is what I'm curious to know. Why do you need them without `u`? Why do you use the representation of a list as a string?

Comment: What you posted already works, so I don't understand the question. I think you don't understand how unicode/bytestrings work and this causes your confusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy way to convert a unicode list to a list containing python strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272066/easy-way-to-convert-a-unicode-list-to-a-list-containing-python-strings)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
>>> import sys
>>> lst = [u'\u5de5', u'\u5de5']
>>> msg = repr([x.encode(sys.stdout.encoding) for x in lst]).decode('string-escape')
>>> print msg
['工', '工']
```

Comment: I've got a one more question related to this.  Pleas see my updated post.

Comment: @gongzhitaao, Where is the `one more question`?

Comment: @gongzhitaao, `more_msg = ...` just works. What is the problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't, `'ascii' codec can't decode byte` is the error message.